# How to process an analog signal into Virtex 6 FPGA (doesn't have ADC built-in, or as daughter card)? Can anyone explain step by step

Tags: adc, virtex-series-fpga

It's for educational purposes. I want to take an analog signal (real time) and process it in FPGA and do some simple operations. I have a Virtex 6 board of Xilinx.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to acquire analog data in an FPGA without an ADC. That's impossible. You need an ADC. Furthermore, the question is too broad for this site, which prefers specific, focused questions that show prior effort or research. For general learning, you're better off using a search engine. In this case, a search term like "FPGA connect ADC" should give you lots of good beginner-level information.

Comment: please remove the `matlab` tab ... there is nothing related to matlab in your post

Comment: You could build a sigma-delta ADC on the side with an op-amp and a few support components? (I've removed the matlab tag for OP)

Comment: Normally you'd build an interface in the FPGA to connect to whichever ADC you choose.